# Verify understanding of contractable spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm self-studying *Using the Borsuk Ulam Theorem* as a neat topics reading, and I have little to no prior experience with algebraic topology (I'm a fair hand in combinatorics, which is what the book is largely about). The first chapter of the book is a crash course in basic background to get to the good stuff. I was hoping that someone could verify my understanding.

A space $X$ is **contractible**, written $X \sim \{e\}$ $(e$ being a dummy variable$)$, if and only if there are continuous maps $f : X \rightarrow \{e\}$ and $g : \{e\} \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f \sim \text{id}_X$ and $f \circ g \sim \text{id}_{\{e\}}$. We say a function $f$ is nullhomotopic if there is a homotopy taking $f$ to a constant function, writing $f \sim 0$.

Here's what I would appreciate being checked. If I were to say $X$ is not contractible, does this amount to $\text{id}_X \not\sim 0$?

Here is my reasoning: all functions $f : X \rightarrow \{e\}$ are continuous, the same can be said for all $g$. Moreover, $f \circ g$ is a function which starts in $\{e\}$, passes through $X$, and ends up in $\{e\}$. This is always going to look like $\text{id}_{\{e\}}$. Thus the negating condition is what I said: that $\text{id}_X$ is not nullhomotopic.

More generally, $X$ is contractible if and only if $\text{id}_X$ is nullhomotopic.

I also could see this making sense where contracting the function $\text{id}_X$ is basically the same thing as contracting the space itself.

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}$Note that there is exactly one continuous map $f : W \to \{e\}$ for all spaces $W$. Also, note that continuous maps $g : \{e\} \to W$ correspond exactly to points $w = g(e) \in W$.

Thus, one can rephrase the definition of "contractible" as: $X$ is contractible iff there is some $x \in X$ such that $\id_X \sim g$, where $g(y) = x$ for all $y \in X$.

In other words, $X$ is contractible iff $\id_X$ is null-homotopic, as you claim.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.